# Override PuTTY IP address on command line

Tags: ssh, windows-10, putty

I'm using PuTTY for VM  management.  The IP address of the VM are grabbed through a command line, inside PuTTY. I've set session for each of the VMs because they use different username and private key, but when the IP address of the VM changes, is there a way to override IP address of a PuTTY session:

```
putty.exe -ip new_ip -load vm_a
```

I tried this but it didn't work. I wanted to use predefined session so that I don't have to specify all other arguments to PuTTY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-load` option causes PuTTY to load configuration details out of a saved session. If these details include a host name, then this option is all you need to make PuTTY start a session (although Plink still requires an explicitly specified host name).

So you can't override ip with only putty.exe, however I feel it is not good practice to keep overriding ip with command line options since you already know ip's, better to change it in saved sessions so you can use it easily.

Hope this will help.

Comment: It was because the ip in the saved session changes, anyway thanks!